# Why am I getting $injector:unpr (unknown provider) in this single page app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Writing a single page angular app, but I am getting the Injector Error (unknown provider).  Do I have to do more to make angular aware of my controller?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="AvailablePets" ng-controller="homeController">
  {{pets}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('AvailablePets', [])
  .controller('homeController', function( $scope ) {
    console.log('App Home Controller');
    // Controller Logic
    $scope.pet = "Dog";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Inline Array Annotation` to inject the dependency in angular

Change to this

```
 var app = angular.module('AvailablePets', [])
      .controller('homeController',['$scope', function( $scope ) {
        console.log('App Home Controller');
        // Controller Logic
        $scope.pet = "Dog";
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change like this,

```
 var app = angular.module('AvailablePets', [])
    app.controller('homeController', function( $scope ) {
        console.log('App Home Controller');
        // Controller Logic
        $scope.pet = "Dog";
    });
```

Also expression should be  `{{pet}}` not `{{pets}}`

```
<body ng-app="AvailablePets" ng-controller="homeController">
  {{pet}}
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xCz00mHpNuzEa52BJycl?p=preview)**

```js
var app = angular.module('AvailablePets', [])
    app.controller('homeController', function( $scope ) {
        console.log('App Home Controller');
        // Controller Logic
        $scope.pet = "Dog";
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="AvailablePets" ng-controller="homeController">
  {{pet}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah, yes the pets/pet was stupid typo, but wasn't the core of the issue so thats good.  This works in the plunker but not inline on an HTML page.  user2181397's answer I believe is correct.

Comment: @BrianKelleher It should work in inline as well, check i have added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

At times forgetting to refer your js files using the src attribute in the  tag also leads to this kind of error.

In your case, you can either remove the var app and define your module directly or define your controller like this app.controller. Both of them works fine.